# Is there a way to detect whether the Accessibility Zoom feature is turned on?

Tags: ios, accessibility

UIKit include UIAccessibility functions for determining whether Voice Over, Closed Captioning, Guided Access, and Invert Colors are turned on. However, I haven't yet been able to find a way to determine if the user has the Zoom feature turned on (Settings > General > Accessibility > Zoom). Does anyone know of a way to get this info?

Comment: you could use UIAccessibilityZoomFocusChanged to detect it, but only after the user has tapped to zooms the view.

Comment: Curious, is there anything your code would do differently based on whether this zoom is enabled or not?

Comment: Thanks, Calvin, I'll give that a shot.

Brendan - I want to automatically switch an app into a high-contrast ADA-compliant theme if the user is using any of the device's accessibility features.

Comment: @NitinAlabur: how to detect the zoom changed with this function? I haven't seen any available notification. Besides, I don't understand how it works because it 's supposed to notify the system and not the opposite (???): using the zoom feature is automatically kniown by the system, isn't it ? Thanks for your return.

Comment: I'm going to question the rationale here: Don't assume that choosing to zoom is an invitation from the user to switch on all the other ADA compliant features you may have prepared. I can even imagine a situation where zoom is desired, but high contrast is not.

Answer (score -1):

Currently, there's no way to detect if the zoom accessibility option is on. This information can reveal some data about the user's device that could be sensitive to them so Apple doesn't provide it. You can implement functionalities around the Zoom option such as having the Zoom focus move to a specific control if necessary and if Zoom is not activated, this will have no effect, so you don't have to worry about whether Zoom is activated or not. The Accessibility API offers a lot of other functionalities that you can check [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/uiaccessibility)

Answer (score -1):

Please try `UIAccessibility.ZoomType` its an `Enum`

[image: UIAccessibility.ZoomType Apple ISO Swift ref.]

You *may have to use it* in combination with `[UIAccessibilityContainer][1]` or `static func zoomFocusChanged(zoomType: UIAccessibility.ZoomType, toFrame: CGRect, in: UIView)`

How do I know this, seems like the code dump on the this shows the following definition inside the `UIkit` for `UIAccessibility.ZoomType` .

```
typealias UIAccessibilityZoomType = UIAccessibility.ZoomType
extension UIAccessibility {
  @available(iOS 5.0, *)
  enum ZoomType : Int {
    init?(rawValue: Int)
    var rawValue: Int { get }
    typealias RawValue = Int
    case insertionPoint
    @available(swift, obsoleted: 3, renamed: "insertionPoint")
    static var InsertionPoint: UIAccessibility.ZoomType { get }
  }
```

---

Incase you are curious, some bonus hopefully helps you on how to do it.. but that's not in scope of your question..

> `swift-ide-test -print-module -module-to-print=UIKit.UIApplication` ....

Comment: Your answer is incomplete. You need to actually show how to use this enum to detect whether the Accessibility Zoom feature is turned on. Using `zoomFocusChanged()` is a no-go as it's only triggered after the user has zoomed the view.